# PDA - Sum of Two Characters = Sum of Two Other Characters

Tags: context-free, automata, pushdown-automata

For one problem I have to solve, I'm given a Language:

```
L = {a^r b^s c^t d^u | r+s = t+u}
```

And from it told to construct a PDA that accepts it. I can construct a PDA for

```
L1 = {a^r b^s | r,s >= 0}
```

And for

```
L2 = {c^t d^u | t,u >= 0}
```

As they are, essentially, the same language. However, I'm confused as to how I can make sure that the sum of characters in `L1` equal those in `L2`

Comment: Both $L_1$ and $L_2$ are regular; you have to get at the non-regular essence.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably build a PDA for the language $\{p^nq^n\mid n \ge 0\}$. If so, you're almost there. Just treat the a's and b's as if they were all p's and the c's and d's as if they were q's, like this (with details elided):

1. Count the a's and b's by pushing a marker on the stack for each one (making sure that all the a's precede any b).
2. Match them up with the c's and d's: for each one seen, pop a marker off the stack (again, making sure that the input is correctly formed).
3. If the stack is empty after having read all the input, accept.

Comment: So, for every `a` I push, I can push something like a `#`, the same with `b`. So the stack would look something like `a#a#b#b#b#`?

Comment: @Delfini. You don't need the a's or b's on the stack, just the counting markers.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. So I just push a specific marker for `c`, and a different one for `d`. Then, for each `c` I read, pop one of its stack markers, and then for each `d` I read, pop one of its stack markers?

Comment: @Delfini. Not quite. You want to see that the number of a's and b's together is equal to the number of c's and d's together, so count the number of a's and b's by pushing a marker (the same one) for every a seen and every b seen. Then, every time you see a c or a d, pop one of the markers off. If after having read all the input, the stack is empty, that will mean that the number of a's and b's in total is equal to the number of c's and d's in total.

Comment: What if I want `r + t = s + u`?

Comment: @Delfini. You can still do this, though it's a bit more complicated. For each $a$, push a + marker. For each $b$, cancel a + marker and if there isn't a + marker, then push a - marker. For each $c$ cancel a - marker and if there isn't a - marker, push a + marker. For each $d$ cancel a + marker and if there isn't a + marker, push a - marker. If there are no markers at the end, accept, else reject. For example, with $a^3b^7c^6d^2$ you'd have +++ after the a's, ---- after the b's, ++ after the c's and nothing after the d's.